# scala manipulating Model object values

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a complex scala Model,

and I want to change the Values of the model.

I tried this:

```
  processSteps.map{
    step => {
      step.prerequisites = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id)
    }
  }
```

But I got this error:

```
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[models.ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel]]
required: Option[Seq[models.ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel]]
```

how can I resolve this error?

Additional information

```
def getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(processStepTemplateId: Int): Future[Seq[ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel]] = {
    db.run(processStepsPrerequisites.filter(p => p.processsteptemplate === processStepTemplateId).result)
}
```

Update:

also tried this:

```
 processSteps.map{
    step => {
      processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id.get).map(a => {
        step.prerequisites ++ a
      })
    }
  }
```

but returns an empty array

Update:

I use this in a map

```
   def getEditProcessTemplateData(processTemplateId: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
//Get all steps of this process templates
val stepIds: Future[Seq[Int]] = processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplateIds(processTemplateId)

val process = for {
  allApprovedProcessTemplates <- processTemplateDTO.getApprovedProcessTemplates //Get all approved process templates
  processTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplateId) // Get the Process Template
  prerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
  postConditions <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPostConditionsDTO.getProcessPostConditionProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
  approvedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.approveprocess)
  trainedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess)
  processSteps <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(processTemplateId)
  // Step prerequisites
  processStepsPrerequisites <- getProcessStepsPrerequisites(stepIds)
  processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate(stepIds)
  processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForStepPrerequisite(stepIds)
  // Step post conditions
  processStepsPostConditions <- getProcessStepsPostConditions(stepIds)
  processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepPostConditionProcessTemplate(stepIds)
  processTemplatesForStepPostConditions <- getProcessTemplateForStepPostCondition(stepIds)
  // Derived processes
  derivedProcesses <- getDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
  processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses <- getProcessStepsDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
  // Process to process step
  processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates <- getProcessStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates(stepIds)
  processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep <- getProcessTemplateToProcessStepId(stepIds)
  responsible <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getResponsibleProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all responsibles for this process template
  accountable <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getAccountableProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all accountables for this process template
  consulted <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getConsultedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
  informed <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getInformedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
} yield (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
  processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
  processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed)





process.map({ case (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed) =>

  processSteps.map{
    step => {
      processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id.get).map(a => {
        step.prerequisites ++ a
      })
    }
  }

  Ok(Json.obj(
    "allApprovedProcessTemplates" -> allApprovedProcessTemplates,
    "processTemplate" -> processTemplate,
    "prerequisites" -> prerequisites,
    "postConditions" -> postConditions,
    "approvedProcessTemplate" -> approvedProcessTemplate,
    "trainedProcessTemplate" -> trainedProcessTemplate,
    //       Step prerequisites
    "processStepsPrerequisites" -> processStepsPrerequisites,
    "processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate" -> processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate,
    "processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites" -> processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites,
    // Step post conditions
    "processStepsPostConditions" -> processStepsPostConditions,
    "processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate" -> processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate,
    "processTemplatesForStepPostConditions" -> processTemplatesForStepPostConditions,
    // Derived processes
    "derivedProcesses" -> derivedProcesses,
    "processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses" -> processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses,
    // Process to process step
    "processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates" -> processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates,
    "processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep" -> processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep,
    "steps" -> processSteps,
    "responsible" -> responsible,
    "accountable" -> accountable,
    "consulted" -> consulted,
    "informed" -> informed
  ))
})
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `processSteps`? `Option[...]` ? And where is that expression being used?

Comment: You should really use shorter method names...

Comment: processSteps is a Future[Seq[ProcesStepsModel]]

Comment: and where is it used? Ie. inside which method/function ?

Comment: updateted it above

Comment: I'm not making my self clear. The compiler expects an Option and you are the type resulting from that expression is a `Future`. You need to show us types. Just variable names wont help... The same question applies, where is `process.map` being used?

Comment: added the full code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks like is that step.prerequisites is the Option[Seq[models.ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel]] and you're trying to assign the future to that, and processSteps is a Future[Seq[ProcesStepsModel]].

what you seem to want to do is along the lines of

```
processSteps.flatMap { psteps: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] =>
    val updateFutures: Seq[Future[Unit]] = psteps.map {
      step => {
        val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id.get)
        prerequisiteFuture.foreach(prereqs => step.prerequisites = Some(prereqs))
      }
    }
    Future.sequence(updateFutures)
} // Has type Future[Unit]
```

It should be noted that mixing Futures and mutations is fraught with peril and brings back in a lot of the issues with concurrency that Futures sort of cured.  I would take a serious look at replacing the assignment with something like (assuming that ProcessStepsModel is a case class):

```
processSteps.map { psteps: Seq[ProcessStepsModel] =>
  Future.sequence(psteps.map {
    step => {
      val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id)
      prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqs => step.copy(prerequisites = Some(prereqs)))
    }
  })
} // Has type Future[Seq[models.ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel]]
```

The object creations might seem expensive, but they're probably not going to be as expensive in practice as the blocking introduced by defensive Awaits (and the timeouts that come hand-in-hand) or the heisenbugs that mutation introduces.

Comment: thanks, I got this error:

`found   : Seq[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel] => scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]
required: models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel => ?

`

Comment: do you maybe have a hint?

Comment: I think its really close to the goal, It would be amazing if you have some minutes to take a look at it again. Thanks :)